# Weight limited very high power transformers

Tags: transformer, space

I'm doing BOTN (back-of-the-napkin) math for electric rockets, specifically the weight of the transformers they would need. At least in principle, one can [derive power from stellar winds](https://tauzero.aero/wp-content/uploads/JBIS-May-2019-Greason.pdf), including our own star. Enough, in fact, that you can forgo needing a nuclear reactor if you want to use a DS4G, or in the case of the JBIS paper there, a LINAC!

One thing I haven't seen explicitly handled yet, however, is the weight of the transformer, hence my question. Every electric rocket I've read about needs high voltages, and lots of power! Size isn't a concern, but weight very much is. How light weight can transformers get if we're getting into MVA or GVA ranges? Expensive materials are fine in this case, since they'd easily pay for themselves in launch costs.

Another potential sticking point is the current reference for this kind of rocket has a 30 Hz power supply. While the authors have stated to be working on an electric analog that can operate at a higher frequency, I am wondering what one would do with such a low frequency. Rectify and invert? Something else entirely?

Comment: Let's see the math and a description of the system elements that you are considering. My ignorant first impression? You have either done a yeoman's job analyzing a complete rocket system, possess a comprehensive view, and only have this one remaining question, nicely narrowed down, but where you are not sharing your detailed thoughts that led you here; or else, you are blinkered and narrowly focusing on one thing you think is important but in fact you really don't have a comprehensive view so this BOTN calc may be of little importance, yet. Either way, I've no interest without more said.

Comment: The referenced paper is interesting. And I'll read it when I get time, for that reason alone. But I can't debate the paper or listen to the author discuss their thoughts. So there's no point discussing it here, since it can't respond to questions or thoughts I may have. You have your own thoughts, though. Write them as clearly as in that paper and show me why the transformer question is important to the rest and I think I'll be much more interested.

Comment: Right now I'm just looking at power/weight estimations to make first-order mass estimations of rockets for different applications. Since I'm still at a very nebulous, abstract stage, I'm looking for similarly broad estimations to figure out mass. From there I can use the rocket equation to determine the mass ratio needed for the missions I had in mind. I also just realized this might be relevant for beam-power applications (a laser, likely using Bessel or Airy beams). kW/kg estimations for rocket and nuclear generation power exist, but transformers are seemingly overlooked so far.

Comment: To really answer the question but still keep it as general as I'd like given this first-pass stage I'm at, basically, I want to look at specific powers for power generation, power gear like transformers, and different sorts of electric rockets so I can build a rocket around a specific mission, be it carrying instruments, people, ordinance, fuel, propellant, or little flags to drop on a moon, modulo how fast or sneaky or efficient the particular application is. Assuming the specific power of terrestrial transformers, those seem to be the limiting factors, unless aerospace transformers exist.

Comment: What study materials have you thoroughly read, with understanding, that apply to your question? You should have compiled quite a list, I'd imagine. It also helps to see what you've seen if the task is to find papers on this supposed 'overlooked' area. In fact, it may simply be you didn't look hard enough or else didn't know where to look or who to ask. Personally? I'd be talking with experts either by email or on the phone (authors on papers) as part of the initial work needed to get up to speed on the topic. And you should be passing along relevant information, with sources, here. My opinion.

Comment: I've found if I give too much contextual info on stackexchange I get endlessly punted to different stack exchange since it's physics or worldbuilding or engineering, heh. I'm writing a novel and I've already sponged atomic rockets/project rho, and networked with quite a few scientists. I've spoken to Greason actually, but he's extremely busy! I haven't searched papers on transformer specific power yet, I was hoping some estimation could be derived from flux density and what materials are recommended to be used for mass-limited high power (high budget) applications.

Comment: Keep in mind that, between increasing frequency and reducing size, even if efficiency stays fixed, power density goes up, and therefore cooling is proportionally more important. On Earth, that's already a challenge with MVA scale transformers having (usually) oil filling and radiator fins, but much more (pumped fluid and larger radiators, perhaps even heat pumps) will be necessary in space. The total optimization will include all these systems, not just the transformer. Likely NASA has materials discussing this, but it's going to be quite niche and hard to find. Good luck.

Comment: I won't pretend to understand much of the linked paper, but as far as constructing a transformer with maximum power/mass ratio, I would think that an air-core (or vacuum core) would theoretically allow arbitrarily high magnetic flux, and superconductive windings would similarly allow very high currents. High power density would also require very high frequency. Upper limits may involve parasitic effects like inter-coil capacitance and insulation breakdown. I'm rather weak on magnetics and high frequency circuits, so further discussion would involve those with such expertise.

Comment: @cthon Yeah, `worldbuilding` does come to mind. I think the story-writing context is important to know. I also understand why you withheld it here as it likely would get punted. But what's one to do? It's not a good idea to hide what's going on, even if you can predict likely behaviors when you expose your hand. I'm not a fiction writer and can't pretend to be good at it. But it sounds like you want some serious info in the story. See if you can interest some 'corresponding author' of some paper in suggesting a grad (or working on a research-intensive master's) student to talk with.

Comment: @cthon On the other hand, perhaps someone here will want to help now that your motivation is better understood and the gods here also won't punt the question. Could happen!

Comment: Vicor apparently manages to get ***8kW per cubic inch*** out of their coin-sized non-isolated, 48/12V step-down [NBM2317 series](https://www.vicorpower.com/industries-and-innovations/automotive/automotive-products) and that's for the ***whole*** power supply, not just the transformer. As a bonus, they even ***look*** like they belong in space - they don't say what they weigh, but at 8kW/in2 I imagine they'd be pretty light compared to more ***conventional*** power supplies...

Answer (score 2):

In order to minimize the amount of material in a transformer, opting for high frequency is certainly the best option. The great majority of the mass of a transformer comes from the core material and the conductive material in the windings. For standard (forward mode) transformers, the number of turns required in the windings is a function of the core's dimensions, the permeability of the core material, and the maximum flux density it can withstand. As the flux in the core is a product of the applied voltage and time divided by the number of turns in the winding, number of turns required is also inversely proportional to the frequency. For low frequency transformers the core is usually made of iron. Iron can withstand high flux density (>1T) without saturation, therefore giving a high power throughput for a given frequency, but its losses increase rapidly with frequency, limiting how small (and light) an iron cored transformer can be for a given power throughput. For high frequency transformers, ferrite is the most common material. Ferrite generally has a lower saturation flux density than iron (0.25T to 0.5T) but its high frequency performance with low losses more than make up for this. Ferrite is rather heavy though, and this could be a problem for your application.

I would suggest the best core material for you would be nanocrystalline. These cores have low loss at high moderately high frequency and high permeability. They also have a saturation flux density higher than ferrite. This would allow the transformer to operate at high frequency and fairly high flux density. This would result in minimal winding mass. The nanocrystalline materials will produce a core lighter than the ferrite equivalent.

Weight may further be reduced by considering the material for the windings. Copper is the normal material, however if weight/size compromise is different, then aluminium may be a better option. It is less conductive than copper but is much lighter. Also, as frequency increases, the effective resistance of the windings increases due to skin effect. This is the phenomenon in which high frequency current tends to flow primarily in the outer regions of a conductor. The effective thickness of this current region is known as the skin depth. Although aluminium has a higher resistivity than copper, this results in a greater skin depth, therefore it is less adversely impacted by skin effect.

Comment: Is a nanocrystalline core lower loss than a molypermalloy powder core? I had thought molypermalloy was the best of the best.

Comment: Nanocrystalline isn't the best in general, but it is very good for certain applications. For something like power distribution through a structure, a highish frequency should be chosen, limited by power transmission distance. If this happens to be in the say 10kHz range, nano can do quite well. If it's over 50kHz, ferrite most likely wins.  Probably laminated iron takes over below 1 or 2kHz. If we're talking MVA on a spaceship, it might be pretty big, so I wouldn't consider anything out of consideration.

Comment: @Hearth MPP is probably the best among *powder* materials. None of them are exceptional at power conversion frequencies (100s kHz), where gapped ferrite reigns (for energy storage), assuming other considerations such as size or cost aren't a high enough priority to override that. MPP (nor any other powder materials) don't come in very high permeability either, making them better for inductors than transformers (in the sense that a transformer isn't intended to store energy).

Comment: Are there many examples of voltamps/kg for these? Also, if you have a very low frequency AC (30 hz) would you be better off with an inverter, or just biting the bullet, so to speak?

Comment: I found an article describing a resonant air-core transformer that achieves 21.6 kW/kg: https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/COMPEL-08-2022-0291/full/html

Comment: @PStechPaul That's very impressive if actually achieved. I wonder if the power/mass figure includes the other resonant components required, and the shielding, which would certainly be necessary.

Comment: It's probably just the transformer. The complete article is behind a paywall, but if you are aligned with a university or other institution, you might get free or discounted access.